# htaccess: Redirect vs. Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was just looking in one of my `.htaccess` files and noticed the following:

```
Redirect /old-page /new-page
```

I was expecting to see `Redirect 301` or `Redirect 302`, but it only said `Redirect` and works just fine.

I'm curios if `301` or `302` isn't indicated what does the redirect default to? 301? 302? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Redirect /old-page /new-page
```

Means use `302` since 302 is default value here.

To use 301:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page /new-page
```

[See 301 directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Comment: Thanks! I figured that was the case, but couldn't find documentation on it. Your link to the Apache Docs states: _If no status argument is given, the redirect will be "temporary" (HTTP status 302)._